# Maven build failure error in opening zip file

Tags: maven, maven-2

I'm getting error when I build my maven project "mvn clean install".
I have the following dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
<version>2.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm getting the following error
[WARNING] The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.8.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.8.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\XXX.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\jaxrs\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider\2.8.9\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.9.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\XXX.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-joda\2.8.9\jackson-datatype-joda-2.8.9.jar; error in opening zip file

I try to solve the problem by deleting .m2\repository and mvn -U clean install still having the same issue..

Comment: Which repository do you use? Can you share the `settings.xml` file if it exists? Do you have any specific `<repository>` configuration in your `pom.xml`? You should share those as well.